# Domain registrar's DNS records vs web hosting DNS records

Tags: dns, webserver, vesta

I bought a domain from Google Domains. I have an A record (on Google Domains DNS control panel) pointed to my server's IP. I had a `www` **CNAME** record pointed to `mydomain.tld`. To experiment with my hosting panel's DNS (I have VestaCP) I deleted the `www` record from Google Domains DNS panel. There was already a `www` **A** record on VestaCP DNS panel. I deleted that and added a `www` **CNAME** record pointing to `mydomain.tld`. And suddenly my `www.mydomain.tld` stopped resolving. I also tried adding a `test` **A** record but I couldn't ping `test.mydomain.tld'.

So, how does hosting panel's DNS work? Each time I add a new website (be it a sub domain or a new domain itself) VestaCP creates certain DNS records. Are these DNS records supposed to override the ones in domain registrar's DNS panel or vice versa? What are DNS records in VestaCP DNS are there for?

Comment: Its a little hard to follow in your question but; are you saying you have `server.mydomain.tld A <public ip>` then `www CNAME server.mydomain.tld` also where do your `NS` entries point at? (Google or Vesta)

Comment: @user3788685 NS entries at Google or Vesta? In Google Domains I have set to use Google's DNS service. In vesta NS points to `ns.localhost.tld`

Comment: Hmm. something seems wrong. Ok, where do you *want* to manage your DNS for that domain? Google or Vesta? And do you currently only use Vesta for your web hosting?

Comment: @user3788685 Yes. I only use vesta for hosting. I actually was wondering if it was possible that I point `@` A record to my servers IP address and let Vesta's DNS manager other DNS records. I was wondering how DNS entries at these two places relate/override.

Comment: The DNS records that are in a effect are the ones in the zone file that resides with your authoritative Name Servers. If you were to look in the whois right now what name servers would be listed?

Comment: @NeilAnuskiewicz It lists Google's nameservers. So, the DNS entries that are created in VestaCP are not in effect?

Comment: That's right. If you're using Google's NS's then that's where the zone file lives so all records must be done in Google. Did you want the authoritative DNS to be at Google or at VestaCP? You can change the DNS to point at VestaCP if you wanted and still use Google for services and vice-a-versa. I'd start with just getting DNS working before getting too fancy though.

Comment: @NeilAnuskiewicz I just wanted to know how it works. I don't like being too fancy myself either.  :P

So, you are saying if I configure to the nameservers to point to VestaCP, then the DNS entries in both would work?

Comment: You have to choose one or the other. There can only be one authoritative DNS so it's got to be either Google or VestaCP. It will only work in one place or the other. Once you have it working you can host services at the other but for the zone file you have to choose where you want to it to live.

Comment: "Once you have it working you can host services at the other" What do you exactly mean by services?

Comment: @NeilAnuskiewicz "The DNS records that are in a effect are the ones in the zone file that resides with your authoritative Name Servers. If you were to look in the whois right now what name servers would be listed?" In practice it is also the nameservers listed in the **parent** that counts, otherwise the final domain is not even found. Then depending on resolvers, if they are child-centric or parent-centric, they stick to one set of `NS` records across the zone cut or the other side of it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your hosting and domain in one single server or with one provider, your domain DNS will be with your domain itself. You just need to point the A record to hosting IP. Your Nameservers will be the default.

If you have your domain with one hosting provider and domain with other then you need to change your domain Nameservers to hosting nameservers. Then your DNS will migrate to your hosting account. The changes you may do in your domain panel will not affect. You can change your DNS settings from your hosting account only.

Hope it helps.